# How to fix pattern="[A-Za-z]" input field

Tags: html, regex

Hey for some reason when i use this(pattern="[A-Za-z]") in my input field nothing will be accepted?

When I enter "Ruben" in this field it just says "make sure the format complies with the requested format"?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `[A-Za-z]` matches single character, `Ruben` is 5 hars long.

You should use `[A-Za-z]+` for pattern instead, which will accept one or more of letters.

You could also use anchors `^[A-Za-z]+$` to make sure input consists of **only** letters.

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="uname">enter test string </label>
    <input type="text" id="uname" name="name" required size="45"
           pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" title="enter test string">
    <span class="validity"></span>
    <p>Input must be at least one letter and ocnsist of only letters.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern matches exactly one character. Add a + quantifier after the character class to make it match one or more of those characters.